# Class structure for Top Trumps card

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Java (and have limited coding skill in general) and am trying to implement a Top Trumps game (games consoles is the theme). It'll be an Android app in the end, but I want to get the mechanics in place first, with text output to see that things work.

Each card in the deck has five categories, all integers, and the same on all cards. I figure these should be static members in a class. Each card also has a boolean, which defines which category is best (the bot player will pick this when it's the bot's turn). I've not created these yet.

I'm struggling, to say the least. What I've got so far is below (only three categories here, but obviously these can be added to).

```
public class Category {
    int stat;
    boolean isBest;

    public Category(int inStat, boolean inIsBest) {
        stat = inStat;
        isBest = inIsBest;
    }
}

public class Card {

    public Card () {
        Category cat1 = new Category(1977, true);
        Category cat2 = new Category(1989, false);
        Category cat3 = new Category(2000, false);
    }
}
```

The trouble here is that I have no way of tying the created categories into one card, so that later I can write, say:

```
if (card1.cat1.stat < 1000) ...
```

Any advice? I've looked extensively online and on here and my head's spinning.

Comment: You should have a list of categories in our `Card` class: `List<Category> categoryList`.

Comment: Thanks. Could you expand on that? List is a new concept for me.

Comment: Basically, see a list as bag where you can store elements of some type. Before going any further, I suggest you to take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) in order to understand its benefits. Also, take a look at [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which is one of the implementations of List and perhaps is the most suitable for you.

Comment: I was planning to use `ArrayList` to create the full deck of cards, and to deal from that into two hands. But first I need to understand how to tie five categories into a single card -- I think!

Comment: Do the amount of categories in each card change or is it always five? And will the card use always the five categories or will it use only just one?

Comment: Each card always has five categories, all used. Each card has the same categories: say, Year of release, RAM size (MB), CPU speed (MHz), Number of games, Geek factor. Each category has a value: say, 1995, 128, 300, 1000, 7. A player chooses a category, states its value, and compares it with the card from the other player. Whoever has the winning value takes the opponent's card and gets to lead first on the next card. Hope that makes sense! Thank you so far.

Comment: As a possible solution, you can check my answer. Take into account that it is a little bit more complex than the one provided by @Yazan. Therefore, perhaps you could use the latter as a first approach and, if you feel like it, use mine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you'll always have five categories, you have two options here:

**1**. Either you place each one of them has attributes of your class

```
public class Card {

    Category yearOfRelease;
    Category ramSize;
    Category cpuSpeed;
    Category nbrOfGames;
    Category geekFactor;

    ...
}
```

**2**. Or you could have them in a collection:

```
public class Card {

    Collection<Category> categories;

    ...
}
```

I'd advise you to follow the second approach.

As a possible solution, you could use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), instead of a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), because it would allow you, later on with your *bot*, to directly access each one of your categories.

So, you could start by creating an enumeration, where you'd place your category types:

```
public enum CategoryType {

    YEAR_OF_RELEASE,
    RAM_SIZE,
    CPU_SPEED,
    NUMBER_GAMES,
    GEEK_FACTOR;

}
```

The definition of your `Category` class could look something like this:

```
public class Category {

    // The category type
    private CategoryType categoryType;

    // The category value
    private int value;

    public Category(CategoryType categoryType, int value) {
        this.categoryType = categoryType;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // getters ands setters
}
```

Your `Card` class could be implemented in the following manner:

```
public class Card {

    // Defines the best category (for later use)
    private CategoryType bestCategoryType;

    // Holds all categories, easily accessible by type
    private Map<CategoryType, Category> categories;

    public Card() {
        categories = new HashMap<>();
        // by default, the year of release will be the best category
        bestCategory = CategoryType.YEAR_OF_RELEASE;
    }

    public void createCategory(CategoryType categoryType, int value, boolean isBest) {
        createCategory(categoryType, value);

        if (isBest) {
            bestCategoryType = categoryType;
        }
    }

    public void createCategory(CategoryType categoryType, int value) {
        Category category = new Category(categoryType, value);
        categories.put(categoryType, category);
    }

    // Attains the best category
    public CategoryType getBestCategoryType() {
        return bestCategoryType;
    }

    // Attains the map of categories
    public Map<CategoryType, Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }
}
```

Finally, the following depicts an example of how you could use it:

```
public class TopTrumps {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // list of cards per user
        List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

        Card card1 = new Card();
        card1.createCategory(CategoryType.YEAR_OF_RELEASE, 1995);
        card1.createCategory(CategoryType.RAM_SIZE, 128);
        card1.createCategory(CategoryType.CPU_SPEED, 300);
        card1.createCategory(CategoryType.NUMBER_GAMES, 1000);
        // for card #1, the geek factor will be the best category
        card1.createCategory(CategoryType.GEEK_FACTOR, 7, true);

        // for card #2, since the best category, by default, is the year of
        // release, we'll leave it as it is
        Card card2 = new Card();
        card2.createCategory(CategoryType.YEAR_OF_RELEASE, 2005);
        card2.createCategory(CategoryType.RAM_SIZE, 256);
        card2.createCategory(CategoryType.CPU_SPEED, 500);
        card2.createCategory(CategoryType.NUMBER_GAMES, 750);
        card2.createCategory(CategoryType.GEEK_FACTOR, 4);

        // we'll add each card to our list
        cards.add(card1);
        cards.add(card2);

        // then, in order to access each category, one could do the following
        for (Card card : cards) {
            // retrieve the best category
            Category bestCategory = card.getCategories().get(card.getBestCategoryType());

            System.out.println("Best category: " + bestCategory.getCategoryType() + "=" + bestCategory.getValue());

            System.out.println("Card categories: ");

            // retrieve each card's category value
            for (Category category : card.getCategories().values()) {
                System.out.println(category.getCategoryType() + "=" + category.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what this game is, but class design wise i suggest this:

you need to add a member to `Card` which is `ArrayList` of categories
then you can fill them using `addCategory()` method in `Card` class:

```
public class Card {
    private ArrayList<Category> categories = null;

    public Card () {
        //initialize categories arraylist
        categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
    }

    public void addCategory(int stat, boolean isBest){
        categories.add(new Category(stat, isBest));
    }

    //use this method to get category at any index (0 - n) to compare with other categories
    public Category getCategory(int index){
        return categories.get(index);
    }
}
```

usage example:

```
Card card1 = new Card();
card.addCategory(1977,true);
card.addCategory(1921,false);
```